# Timatic: Valid China visa in old passport (British) - Tajikistan to China by air?

Tags: visas, china, uk-citizens, passport-renewals, tajikistan

I am a British citizen with a valid Chinese tourist visa is an expired passport, and I have a new passport. I've heard reports that it's fine to enter China like this, despite the fact that officially on the UK visa for China application website it says you can't (I once phoned and the woman said it was fine, despite what it says on the website). Can anyone comment? (British passport holders only!)

Secondly, my embarkation point is Tajikistan (Dushanbe airport) flying to Ürümqi in China, not from the UK. Will this be OK to fly according to Timatic? I will probably be flying with a Chinese airline.

Comment: I can't address British passports, but as a US passport holder with a 10-year visa (what they normally issue Americans) I have done this multiple times, no problem with the Chinese authorities.  (Nobody else seems to be able to figure out the visa is in the other passport, though.  Hey, there's a reason I handed you two passports rubber-banded together!  Try looking where that rubber band goes through the second passport!)

Answer (score 1):

After some searching, I could not find an answer to this on the People's Republic of China Embassy to the UK website.

But I was able to find this question in the FAQ ([Frequently Asked Questions](http://losangeles.china-consulate.org/eng/visa/chinavisa/t1448697.htm)) section of the Chinese consulate in Los Angeles:

> *I have got a new passport but my valid visa is in my previous passport. Can I use the two passports to enter China?*
>
> If your personal data such as your name, sex, date of birth, nationality in your new passport remain the same as your previous passport and the purpose of your next tour to China remains the same as permitted in your previous visa, you may use the two passports together to enter China. You need not apply for a new visa with the new passport.
>
> If any information mentioned above is changed, you must apply and pay for a new visa with your new passport and your previous visa will be cancelled without refund.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to bring your old Passport, new Passport, and China Visa.

Comment: Welcome to the site Cherrycc. Can you please give a link to an official site or at least tell where you have found that information? It is the general rule but this is a special situation and the information so far does not agree.

Comment: I am a TripAdvisor in China. I have helped some travelers with 10 years China Visa with an expired passport to go to China. You just need to take the old passport, new passport, and Chinese Visa.

Comment: This is not true, it will heavily depend on the customs and the city where you are entering, according to China rules you must change your visa when you get a new passport, anything else is asking for trouble, they might be nice to you but don’t count on it, I travel a lot and I live in China and change my passports every 2 years or so and every time I do I have to change my visa to match my new passport as well that’s the rules.